# Extend Dictionary to function for JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

The target of my code is to extend the Dictionary.
Because I would like to put and get some value from JSON object

Here is my code:

```
typealias JSONObject = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

protocol JSONKey {
    func toString() -> String
}

extension String: JSONKey {
    func toString() -> String { return self }
}

extension Dictionary where Value: AnyObject {
    func getInt(JSONKey key: String) -> Int? {

    }
    mutating func put(key:String, value:AnyObject) {
        let Testvalue : NSDictionary = [key: value]
    }
}
```

Is that possible to implement it?

The result will like :

function Put :

```
var Test1 = ["a", 123]

Test1.put("b", 456) -> which will be put inside the dictionary
```

function getInt :

```
var Test2 = ["c", 555]

Test2.getInt["c"] = 555
```

Comment: Be careful what words you're using. A dictionary is not a JSON object.

Comment: Thanks, I know that is really similar. Just want to have some function like dictionary and collect it as a JSON Object.

Comment: This is not the same. A JSON object can *contain* a dictionary or an array. // I don't see anything about JSON in your code, there's only stuff about dictionaries.

Comment: There are several Swift frameworks for working with JSON (i.e. Unbox https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox). You are probably better off using one of those than inventing these things yourself.